# htaccess redirect to sample.php file if URL contains a certain string like "catalogsearch/result/?q="

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This condition is checking result only :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)result(.*)$
```

But I need condition like this :

```
catalogsearch/result/?q=
```

So then I redirect to **`samlie.php`** file in root.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)catalogsearch/result(.*)$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule (.*) rewrite-strtolower.php?rewrite-strtolower-url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

%{REQUEST_URI} string does not contain url querystring it just contains the uri (url part after hostaname and before ? ie **/catelogsearch/search** ) . To match against querystring, you need to use %{QUERY_STRING}

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=
RewriteRule ^uri /destinationpath/? [L,R]
```

This rule will redirect **/uri?q=** to **/destinationpath** .

Comment: ok, but if we use RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=
 it will check all query strings but i need it to check only "/catelogsearch/search" not to all like "search/results"